# exhaustion by compactness

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, compactness, topological-vector-spaces

Let $V \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ show that there exists a sequence $(K_m)_{m \in \mathbb N}$ of subsets of $V$ that satisfies :

$(i) K_m \subset K_{m+1}$

$(ii) \cup_{n \in \mathbb N} K_m = V$

First i considered $V = \mathbb R^n$ and i did show part $(i)$ easily. But i do not know how to show **part $(ii)$.**

For the case $V \subset \mathbb R^n$ i have to use $K_m := \{x\in \mathbb R^n \vert d(x,A) \ge \frac{1}{m}\}$  for some suitable set $A$. But i do not know, how to choose an $A$ so that $K_m$ will be **compact**.

How should i approach $(i)$ and $(ii)$ for $V \subset \mathbb R^n$ and $V = \mathbb R^n$?

Comment: You missed in the questoion, did you mean to say that the $K's$ are compact?

Comment: @Alan I have to show that $(K_m)_{m \in N}$ satisfies $(i)$and $(ii)$ in order to do that i need to define $K_m$ as given in Exercise and i have to choose $A$ so that $K_m$ for all $m \in N$ is compact.

Comment: Is it $K$, or is it $F$? Also, obviously compactness can't be demanded if $V$ isn't an $F_\sigma$ subset of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: $A$ is the same $\forall m$? Because in that case $\cup K_m\subseteq A^{c}$, so if $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ you have no way to find it in that way

Comment: @SaucyO'Path that was a stupid mistake from me i  wrote F instead of K. Now i corrected it :)

Comment: @ecrin I am free to choose what ever A i want. It should not be the same for all $m$

Comment: What kind of set is $V$ allowed to be? It is not stated................Not every subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ set.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet $V$ is allowed to be an open set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to take $$K_m=\bar{B}(0,m)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n| d(0,x)\le m\}.$$

It is clear that $K_m$ is compact and it satisfies both $(i)$ and $(ii)$.

In fact, $K_m$ is a closed ball in $\mathbb R^n$, then it is compact.

On the other hand, let $y\in\mathbb R^n$, it exists $M\in\mathbb N$ large enough that $d(0,y)\le M$. Then $$y\in K_M\subseteq\cup K_m,$$ that is $\mathbb R^n\subseteq\cup K_m$.

If you want to write it as $$K_m=\{x\in\mathbb R^n|d(x,A)\ge\frac{1}{m}\}$$ it suffices to define $A_m$ as the set $B\left(0,m+\frac{1}{m}\right)^{c}$, while I don't understand why you need this description.

Comment: Thank you very much. How can i prove that $K_m$ as you defined is compact?

Comment: It is a closed ball, so it is closed and limited, that is being compact in $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: the Problem is that i should "show" that it satisfies (i) and (ii). I can easily show (i) but i can't show (ii). Would you please show me how its done? :) Thank you a lot for your Help...

Comment: I edited the answer